# Clear Failed Airflow DAG But Don't Restart

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm running a custom backfill script that backfills a DAG serially. (If I run the backfill concurrently, I either run into a deadlock problem or a Serializable isolation problem.) As part of the process, I sometimes have failed DAGs mixed in with non-existing dates.  To backfill that failed date, I need to clear it first. The problem comes in that a cleared DAG auto restarts and conflicts with the first date running in the backfill.

`airflow clear dag_id -f -s 01-01-20 -e 01-12-20 -f`

Because of the way it is built, I'll have to rewrite it from scratch and clear each backfill individually. If I can prevent a cleared DAG from rerunning, I would save me some time. Is there a way to do this in the `cli`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the [`max_active_runs`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html) argument to `1` when creating the `DAG` object. This will ensure that no more than one execution is active at a time, that way you can clear as many as you'd like and let Airflow handle the rest.